# How to resolve SEHException, VB .NET 2010

Tags: vb.net

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException was unhandled
  Message=External component has thrown an exception.
  Source=mscorlib
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.CloseHandle(IntPtr handle)
       at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.ReleaseHandle()
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.InternalFinalize()
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Finalize()
  InnerException:
```

I read all posts about SEHException but I can't resolve mine, please help. Here is the code I suspect :

```
If hWinUSBInterface = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE And hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then

    If Not tmrAutoConnect.Enabled Then
        RaiseEvent Notify(2, "Not connected")
    End If
    Return
End If

Try
    If hWinUSBInterface <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then
        WinUsb_Free(hWinUSBInterface)
        hWinUSBInterface = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
    End If

    If hDevice <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then

        If CloseHandle(hDevice) Then
            hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
            RaiseEvent Disconnected()
        Else
            Dim ErrorStatus As Integer = Err.LastDllError
            RaiseEvent Error(1, ErrorStatus, "Disconnect")
        End If

    End If
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: The exception is not raised by this code.  You are probably using a FileStream constructor that takes an IntPtr.  Then don't call CloseHandle(), the FileStream's finalizer already does that.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using kernel32.dll CloseHandle on SafeFileHandle hDevice.  The garbage collector is unaware of these CloseHandle calls and will generate this error when it tries to clean up the SafeFileHandle.  Try using hDevice.Close() instead.